# Ruby on rails refuses to connect blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems

Created a blog on ruby on rails (AWS cloud 9) on using "rails new blog" function and I have done the bundle install and bundle update function, as well as updating the gem file so that it says '1.3.13' next to sqllite.

At first it was giving me trouble with me IP address so I whitelisted it in `blog/environments/development.rb` and it still does not work. Every time I hit Preview Running Application it gives me an error on the page and the notice

```
"5fd767abc85042af81a0e01a4ac878ed.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com refused to connect."
```

I have absolutely no idea how to fix this and I have been trying everything to get it to work, and I need to fix this before I continue in my course on web development.

The text below is what I get after hitting Preview Running Application, which seems to be error free to me. Any help is appreciated.

```
Started GET "/" for 100.8.21.33 at 2020-11-20 23:59:50 +0000
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"internal"=>true}
  Rendering /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (2.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 8.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Is there a larger stacktrace at all?  You have the DB and all that connected?  You mentioned `development.rb` but this sounds like it is in production, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who has the same problem as me and sees this in the future: AWS is weird and prints that crashed screen, but your website (unless you have other issues) still works. Once you hit preview running application, pop it out into a new tab and it should work. That was the problem with mine.